# dot net core setting redirect_uri for OpenIdConnect is not same like dot net framework?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, okta, owin-middleware

On a .Net When i create a Open ID connect Authentication Options I have a property to set the RedirectUri this is even defined as recommended on the documentation but no such property exists on the AspNetCore it is automatically set to the current url entered by the user?

The issue what we are facing is, if the user enters the URL with different casing (mix of small case and upper case) then Okta is looking for the exact match of the URL (which is expected) to be passed in the redirectUri. we don't have an option in dot net core to inject the redirectUri in pipeline and the framework automatically getting from URL entered by the user? is this bug fixed in the next versions of aspnet core? can some one advise on this?

is this still an open issue with dot net core 2.x version? any one managed to use the redirecturi from the OWIN pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the override on the Events object for [OnRedirectToIdentityProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-5.0%5D) to control behaviour?

```
services.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.ToLower();
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    };
});
```